# Obstacle detection for ground robot using aerial image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

[image: Result of the code]I want to perform obstacle detection for a ground robot by using a picture taken by a drone of the area the ground robot will cover. Since I have limited background in image processing I am not sure how to carry this out. I tried using the following method but the result is not very accurate. It detects very small edges also and it does not work well with aerial images.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//----------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN
//----------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// src image
    Mat src;
//grayscale image
    Mat gray;
// edges image
    Mat edges;
//dst image
    Mat dst;
//eroded image
    Mat erosion;
//smoothed result
    Mat result;

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Image loading
//----------------------------------------------------------
    namedWindow("result");
    namedWindow("src");
    namedWindow("edges");
    src = imread("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/SDP/obstacle detection/obstacle detection/obstacle detection/shapes.jpg");

//----------------------------------------------------------
//Specifying size and type of image
//----------------------------------------------------------
    edges = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    gray= Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    erosion = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    result = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);

//----------------------------------------------------------
//Converting from RGB to grayscale
//----------------------------------------------------------
    cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

//----------------------------------------------------------
//Edge Detetcion using OpenCV Canny Edge Detector function
//----------------------------------------------------------
    Canny(gray, edges, 80, 255);

//----------------------------------------------------------
//Filling in the non-obstacle areas with white
//----------------------------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i<edges.cols; ++i)
    {
        int j = edges.rows - 1;
        for (j = edges.rows - 1; j>0; --j)
        {
            if (edges.at<uchar>(j, i)>0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        dst(Range(j, dst.rows - 1), Range(i, i + 1)) = 255;
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Appying erosion function to remove noise 
//----------------------------------------------------------
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(10, 10));
   erode(dst,erosion,element);

 //----------------------------------------------------------
 //Smoothing the edges to get result
 //----------------------------------------------------------


    GaussianBlur(erosion, result, Size(5,5), 4);


//----------------------------------------------------------    
// Displaying the intermediate and final resulting images
//----------------------------------------------------------
    namedWindow("src", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("src", src);

    namedWindow("edges", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("edges", edges);

    namedWindow("dst", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("dst", dst);

    namedWindow("erosion", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("erosion", erosion);

    namedWindow("result", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("result", result);




//----------------------------------------------------------
// Wait key press
//----------------------------------------------------------
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

The code takes in an image, converts it to grayscale. Then canny edge detection is used to detect edges of all the objects in the image. This edge detected image s filled with white color starting from the bottom until an edge is detected. The process continues until the whole image is covered. The result is a binary image with white color for areas without obstacles and and black color for obstacles. The opencv function erode is then used to remove unnecessary noise.

I would really appreciate it if I get suggestions on how to improve this or use any other technique.

Comment: Please add some summary and/or explanation of how your code works, or is supposed to work.

Comment: Also, please explain why you tagged python, I only see C++. People get annoyed by tag spam.

Comment: Add the explanation to the question itself, not into the comments. Also, provide an example image -- maybe mark manually what parts you would like to get detected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest thresholding the image for a color range matching the ground. This approach works well, if the color of your ground does not change too much (which is the case in your src image). [You might want to check out this OpenCV example (Python).](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)